# Disabling objects on all but 1 canvas when copying canvases?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have this set of canvases and a function that copies the first canvas to the rest. How can I make all but the first canvas unselectable/uneditable?

**I've tried adding things like the following to each canvas, aside from c0, without luck:**

```
c1.selection = false;
c1.forEachObject(function(o) {
  o.selectable = false;
});
```

Here's my code now, and [here's a fiddle of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/ffmo8j2c/6/):

```js
var canvas = [];
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c' + i));
}

console.dir(canvas);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});

canvas[0].add(rect);

$('#copyBtn').click(function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
table {
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="copyBtn">Copy</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c0" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c1" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c2" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c3" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c4" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c5" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c6" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c7" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any user interaction you can create an object of [fabric.StaticCanvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html).

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = [];
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c' + i));
}
canvas.push(new fabric.StaticCanvas('sc1'));

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});

canvas[0].add(rect);

$('#copyBtn').click(function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="copyBtn">Copy</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c0" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 208px;height: 360px;position: relative;">
       <canvas id="sc1" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c1" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c2" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c3" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c4" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c5" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="c6" width="208" height="360"></canvas>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks promising, how might I apply it to all of the others?

Comment: Create staticcanvas instead normal canvas object for all.

Comment: I've been trying to do what you suggested. [What am I doing wrong here?](https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/4oxepfwc/11/)

Comment: Try to debug, check console. You are getting error, because it is not able to find element having c1 then c2 id

Comment: @code4ever Here is updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oxepfwc/14/). Check the id of canvas, for first I created `fabric.Canvas` for rest created `fabric.StaticCanvas` inside loop.

Comment: This makes so much more sense. Thank you Durga!